# I'm receiving the following error: Unknown column 'idt.amt' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, list, join

The below statement is raising this error:

> Unknown column 'idt.amt' in 'field list'

```
 SELECT
     c.name,
     c.addr1,
     c.addr2,
     c.city,
     c.state,
     c.zip,
     i.invoiceID,
     p.description,
     idt.amt,
     idt.qty
 FROM
     customer AS c
 JOIN
     invoicehdr AS i ON c.customerID = i.customerID
 JOIN
     invoicedtl AS idt ON i.invoiceID = idt.invoiceID
 JOIN
     product AS p ON idt.prodID = p.prodID;
```

`amt` exists in `invoicedtl` table. Given that, what could the problem be here?

Comment: Post the create of the tables to see more details

Comment: pretty sure that is funny :)

Comment: show structure of your invoicedtl table....

Comment: We are pretty sure that you've a typo in your column name or this specific doesn't exist is the table `invoicedtl`...